# Why am I getting "NameError" from input()?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, nameerror

I am new and trying to create a simple "guess the number game":

```
import random
class Randgame :

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def restart(self):
        response = input("Type Yes To Play Again!").lower()
        if response == "yes":
            self.play()
        else:
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            pass

    def play(self):
        guess = int(input("What's your guess?"))
        num = random.randint(0, 10)

        if guess == num:
            print("Correct!")
        else:
            print("Nope!")
        self.restart()


fun = Randgame()

fun.play()
```

All is well until I get to the restart() method. If I type "yes" into the console I get this response:

> NameError: name 'yes' is not defined

I cannot figure this out to save my life and I don't know what to look up. Please help!

Comment: In Python 2.x, `input()` accepted Python expressions, rather than strings.  If for some strange reason you cannot upgrade to a Python version that's actually still supported, you need to replace it with `raw_input()` everywhere you use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, getting input as plain text is done via `raw_input` instead of `input`. Python 3 changed the name of the function to `input`. The Python 2 version of `input` does `eval(raw_input(prompt))`, so it is trying to actually access a variable called `yes`, when you just want to get the string `"yes"`.

[Python 2 Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input)